# Return custom timestamp

Tags: python, linux, hook, reverse-engineering

I have a Linux executable binary file (C or C++ compiled). At some point the program uses a timestamp to generate random numbers

I need to achieve a certain sequence of the random numbers, so I want to make a script (Preferable python) that intercepts the call to the system (AFAIK this is called "hooking") to obtain the timestamp and return a custom value until I get the sequence I need. I have to do this way as the executable doesn't use the entire timestamp, just something like `timestamp % 10000`

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done from *within* the kernel. So you can't use Python (or any other userspace program), you'll have to use C.

One option is to do it in a loadable kernel module.
You can find an example e.g. [here](https://tnichols.org/2015/10/19/Hooking-the-Linux-System-Call-Table/).

Answer (score 1):

With the library preload mechanism, it's possible to intercept and replace calls. For a binary which has been dynamically linked with the C library, you can intercept calls `time()` and alike to emulate a different time.

The open source "libfaketime" project already implements faking time: https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime